# adding jars to a project in eclipse is not under any folder

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-kepler

I'm working on eclipse-kepler.
when I try to add external jars, they are added under the project and not under any folder (that is under the project),
Is there a way I can abbreviate (shorten/shrink) them so it wouldn't be so annoying?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what is your issue.

If you would like to filter out libraries, there is a magical button, a white triangle on the top bar of the *Package Explorer*. There you can filter out all the libraries with a click so they won't be enumerated ([see this screenshot](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/images/xpackageexplorer20_filter.png.pagespeed.ic.bctUi0X01R.png)).

If the issue is that they are included as external Jars (which I'd discourage, since it becomes harder to set up the project in a different environment both for you and others), simply create a *lib* folder, copy the Jar there and include it as simple Jar files (that way the .classpath file won't have any absolute paths).

Actually this feature is quite handy, it saved me a dozens of times. When there is a problem with a class you are using you can easily locate it by opening the type with `Ctrl+Shift+T` and linking it with the editor. It can go into the Jar files and show you where is it. When there is a Claspath conflict it can be a life saviour.